# JVM Super Constructor Calls

Tags: java, constructor, jvm, bytecode-manipulation

Working with compilers for JVM bytecode, I have noticed something about constructors that doesn't make much sense:

Every constructor of every Java class calls a `super` constructor, even direct subclasses of `Object`. This is enforced by the Java Compiler (when it can't implicitly add a call at the beginning of a constructor) and by the Bytecode Verifier, as shown in this error using a custom `.class` file:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return
Exception Details:
  Location:
    dyvil/test/Main.<init>()V @0: return
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b1
```

In the case of a subclass of some random class with fields etc. this makes sense since these fields have to be initialized, but in the case of a subclass of `Object`, this is a *very* common call (+ method invocation overhead) to a nop-method. That raises a few questions:

1. Why is this behavior enforced by the JVM?
2. Is it important that the super class gets loaded / initialized before the subclass? Can't this be ensured before the constructor is called (at subclass initialisation)?
3. In the case of `Object`, the class should already be loaded at any given point, so why the need to call its constructor?
4. Is this useless call optimized away by the JIT Compiler?

EDIT: The Bytecode of `Object`s constructor

```
public void <init>()
   L0
    LINENUMBER 37 L0
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 0
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

As you might be able to see, this constructor does nothing at all.

Comment: Is the question essentially "Does a new instance of Object have to do any work as part of its construction?"?

Comment: That and why it is important / enforced to call the `Object` constructor from any subclass.

Comment: Well, if the answer to "does an Object instance need to do work during construction" is "yes", then surely the answer to that follow-on question is also obviously "yes"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a single `RETURN` in `Object.<init>` does not mean that `Object`'s constructor is NOP.

`Object` class is typically a JVM intrinsic, JVM knows much more about it than just its bytecode. For example, HotSpot uses `Object.<init>` [to register finalizers](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/9d6eb2757167/src/share/vm/interpreter/rewriter.cpp#l101).

The best thing about `Object.<init>` is - it's the only method inevitably called on **any** instance allocation. Look what a powerful feature it is: you can set a single breakpoint on `Object.<init>` to intercept all constructors at once. You can also use Instrumentation API to modify `Object`'s constructor to trace all allocations, and so on...

As to performance - yes, JIT compiler eliminates unnecessary method calls when they are not needed, e.g. when there are no breakpoints on this method, no `finalize` etc. This is true for other trivial methods as well, not only for `Object.<init>`. So they have no performance impact.

Comment: Wow, I did not yet come across the rewriter. Interesting stuff!

Answer (score 1):

1. With the exception that is has no superclass, `Object` is a class like every other. It has a constructor that has to be called. The JVM specification does not preclude `Object` from having instructions in its instance initialization method.
2. It is because static initializers are executed as the class is loaded ([yes, you can avoid that if you load the class manually](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-boolean-java.lang.ClassLoader-)). Even if they were called at instantiation time, it is specified that the hierarchy has to be consistent at loading time. And sometimes a specification is your only reason.
3. Loading a class and creating an instance are two very different things. In fact, Hotspot loads all classes from `java.lang` (if I remember correctly, it has been a long time since I read the code) at VM startup. Also see 1.
4. That I don't know but if I haven't overlooked anything, I guess it's possible. I highly doubt that a lot of time is spent calling `Object`'s constructor in any case, though. If you think it does: measure!